# Add HTML linebreaks with Python regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to add HTML linebreaks (`<br />`) to a string at all line endings which are not followed by a blank line. This simple pattern works:

```
body = re.sub(r'(.)\n(.)', r'\1<br />\2', body)
```

But I realized it will not work for an edge case where a line contains only a single character (because the character would have to be part of two different overlapping matches). So I tried the following pattern with lookaround subpatterns:

```
body = re.sub(r'(?<=.)\n(?=.)', r'<br />', body)
```

This works as intended, except that the HTML tag is added after the linebreak (`\n`), and with an additional linebreak:

```
linebreak
<br/>
!
<br/>
linebreak
<br/>
l
<br/>
works
```

I would expect that the matched linebreak is substituted by the HTML tag (thereby effectively removing the linebreaks from all matching areas) – why does the tag appear on a new line instead (i.e. increasing the number of linebreaks/lines)?

The equivalent pattern in vim does remove the linebreaks:

```
s:\(.\)\zs\n\ze\(.\):\<br \/\>:ge
```

Comment: Maybe you have CRLF endings? Try `re.sub(r'(?<=[^\r\n])\r?\n(?=[^\r\n])', r'<br />', body)`. Note that `.` in Python `re` matches CR symbols.

Comment: I did try `\r?\n` as the pattern (although I am on a Unix system), two newlines in a row are not matched by the pattern (as intended). So the replacement behaviour is what I am confused about. But I tried your suggestion for the lookaround patterns anyway – same result.

Comment: If that does not work, please provide a working reproducible sample code showcasing the issue.

Comment: I tried [this demo](https://tio.run/##PcsxDoMwEETR3qfYVGukiBRpIVxkm1g4igWZtRajiNMbkoJqXjE/b@WtuNeaPlmtkEXngo4b9cRzQgwWn9NFcHoWfNWmRSB4qQr4DCy2yxq8sR@6vm0EfjiGr2TcBaPb4@Dv2rhsCcX/XesO) and it looks like it's working as supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite embarrassing – the pattern/my script do indeed work as supposed to. I was fooled by an HTML source viewer which obviously adds linebreaks to the source code it should display unaltered. Sorry for taking your valuable time.